# I need to upload an image and display it along with a form

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
self.response.out.write(image_resp.read())
self.response.write(form)
```

This displays only the image. The form is out of sight. Is there a way i can display my form along with an image.?

```
#edit 1
new_image = image_resp.read()
```

adding  is also not working.

Comment: You mean you want to _read an image_ that is _uploaded_ via a form?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Insert your image into form. For example like this:

```
<img src="image" alt="image" width="42" height="42">
```

or if you need dynamically loaded image use template engine jinja2 like this:

```
self.response.write(jinja2.render_template(html_template, **context)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Wild guessing what you are trying to achieve without templating:

It seems you are missing the out. I presume the data is correct.

```
    # Don't send headers if you want also a form
    #self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
    self.response.out.write(image_resp.read())
    self.response.out.write(form)
```

Also start with templating. So far your approach is not doing well. You try to display both the form and a form with headers that point to an image.